# Is Oracle's CAST ON CONVERSION ERROR that buggy?

Tags: oracle, casting, oracle19c

I'm trying Oracle's `CAST` with the `ON CONVERSION ERROR` clause for the first time and results are not what I am expecting.

Let's start with `CAST` without the clause:

```
SELECT CAST(123456  AS NUMBER(1,0)) FROM DUAL;

ORA-01438: "value larger than specified precision allowed for this column"
```

The number 123456 is longer than a `NUMBER(1,0)`. It is not magically truncated to one digit somehow, but an error is raised. Good. This is what I expected to happen.

```
SELECT CAST('123456'  AS VARCHAR2(4 CHAR)) FROM DUAL;

Result = '1234'
```

The string '123456' is longer than a `VARCHAR2(4 CHAR)`. It doesn't fit. I must admit I expected a conversion error as with the number, instead of the string getting mutilated.

```
SELECT CAST(123456  AS NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT -1 ON CONVERSION ERROR) FROM DUAL;

Result: 123456
```

How is that? Suddenly there is no problem with the number 123456 not fitting into `NUMBER(1,0)` and the whole number is returned?

```
SELECT CAST('123456'  AS VARCHAR2(4 CHAR) DEFAULT 'too long' ON CONVERSION ERROR) FROM DUAL;

ORA-00907: "missing right parenthesis" at position 43
```

I have looked again and again; I don't see any missing parentheses here.

Is my thinking faulty? Or is `CAST`, especially concerning the `ON CONVERSION ERROR` clause, flawed?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `ON CONVERSION ERROR`.Refer the Table `Casting Built-In Data Types` in this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CAST.html#GUID-5A70235E-1209-4281-8521-B94497AAEF75). Only those conversions tagged with `Note3` can use `ON CONVERSION ERROR`.
You can also read the `Note3` for more details

For your second issue you have to mention the `format` after `ON CONVERSION ERROR` as you can mention in `TO_NUMBER`

```
  SELECT CAST(123456  AS number(1,0) DEFAULT -1 ON CONVERSION ERROR,9) FROM 
  DUAL;
```

Comment: Ah, that explains the missing parantheses in my last query. `ON CONVERSION ERROR` is not allowed on `CAST TO VARCHAR2`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

--Use TRUNC keyword to convert to base date,

```
with src as( select to_date('05-APR-2021', 'DD-MON-YYYY') as sourcetest from dual union all
   select to_date('04/05/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY') as sourcetest from dual )
seLect sourcetest 
    ,trunc(sourcetest) as trunc_date
    ,to_char(trunc(sourcetest), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as to_char_fmt
    --,validate_conversion(sourcetest as date) as test_result   --missing right parenthesis error!!!!!
from src;
```